# KDE software settings going back to default after computer restart

Tags: kde, gui, settings, system-settings, cursor-theme

I've re-applied my settings a couple of times after turning off my computer in KDE software settings. I've done some digging around and couldn't find anything to resolve the situation. One of the problems I was having was my GUI and also my cursor setting back to default after a restart. I'm running an HP model# G360-535DX

Comment: Is this an installed system? Or a LiveUSB? Exactly what method was used to install Ubuntu?

Comment: installed from the terminal

Comment: What does that mean? It is not clear how you installed Ubuntu...and that is key information we need.

Comment: Well, this might have been pre-installed so forgive me for lack of better terminology as of right now. I know that Ksoftware settings can have different themes installed. When I apply, the theme works. When I turn off my machine and then turn my machine back on anytime then the themes are set back to default.

Comment: It seems like you are running some kind of read-only image, the same way an install LiveUSB (test environment) is read-only. That's different from a real, installed OS, which is persistent. Since you don't seem to know how Kubuntu was installed, the amount of help we can offer is limited. You could always *really* install Kubuntu, of course.

Comment: Do you get any results with `find . '!' -user $USER -ls`?